# How do I get the index of a row where max value is not duplicated?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, group-by, max

Given this df

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd

data = StringIO('''gene_variant gene    val1    val2    val3
b1  b   1   1   1
b2  b   2   11  1
b3  b   3   11  1
c2  c   1   1   1
t1  t   1   1   1
t2  t   12  2   2
t4  t   12  3   2
t5  t   1   4   3
d2  d   11  1   2
d4  d   11  1   1''')
df = pd.read_csv(data, sep='\t')
```

How do I get the gene_variant for each gene where; the gene_variant corresponds to the max value for val1 if the max value is not duplicated, and if it is duplicated, the gene_variant corresponds to the max value for val2 if the max value for val2 is not duplicated, or then just max for val3? I.e., any tiebreakers are decided by the next column until the third option.

EDIT: The column val2 is only considered if the max val in val1 is a duplicated/a tie. Same for val3. If the max val in val1/2 is duplicated/is a tie then the values in those columns are no longer considered. Only the values in 1 column at a time are compared.

I've been trying solutions based on:

```
df.groupby('gene').agg(max)
```

and:

```
df.groupby('gene').rank('max')
```

But I can't get there without dropping out into iteration...

The correct answer would be:

```
b3 3
c2 1
t5 4
d2 2
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Wouldn't you expect `t4 3` as your result because `val1` is `2` for `t4` but `1` for `t5`? Or am I misunderstanding the question?

Comment: Hi @maow. Sorry I must not have been clear enough. There are 4 gene_variants for gene t, val1 has a tie for max (2) so I need the gene_variant for the max value fro val2 (4).

Comment: but `t3` and `t4` win the tiebraker. Isn't `t5` already out by this point, because it has `val1 = 1`?

Comment: no. The values in each column are independent.

Comment: Are `gene_variant` unique per group? Is possible multiple columns without duplicated? Then max is count from all columns?

Comment: Yes gene_variant are unique per group. Yes - is possible multiple columns (val1, val2, or val3) without duplicated values. I don't understand the 3rd question, sorry.

Comment: OK, so if non duplicated columns `val1, val2` is count only from `val1` ? Also if possible in `val2` is maximum greater like maximum of val1 still is count max of val1?

Comment: Correct. I'll update the example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If need maximum only for groups with no duplicated values is possible use:

```
#per groups count number of unique values
df1 = df.groupby('gene').transform('nunique')

#compare columns with `gene_variant` and set NaN if duplicates per columns
 
#if maximum is count from all columns if not duplicated values get max
max1 = df.where(df1.eq(df1.pop('gene_variant'), axis=0)).max(axis=1)

#if max is count by order - first val1, then val2
#back filling missing values and select first column
max1 = df.where(df1.eq(df1.pop('gene_variant'), axis=0)).bfill(axis=1).iloc[:, 0]

#assign column by maximum
df = df.assign(max1 = max1)

#get rows from original with maximum max1 per groups
df = df.loc[df.groupby('gene', sort=False)['max1'].idxmax(), ['gene_variant','max1']]
print (df)
  gene_variant  max1
2           b3   3.0
3           c2   1.0
7           t5   4.0
8           d2   2.0
```

How it working:

```
df1 = df.groupby('gene').transform('nunique')

s = df1.pop('gene_variant')

print (df.where(df1.eq(s, axis=0)))
  gene_variant gene  val1  val2  val3
0          NaN  NaN   1.0   NaN   NaN
1          NaN  NaN   2.0   NaN   NaN
2          NaN  NaN   3.0   NaN   NaN
3          NaN  NaN   1.0   1.0   1.0
4          NaN  NaN   NaN   1.0   NaN
5          NaN  NaN   NaN   2.0   NaN
6          NaN  NaN   NaN   3.0   NaN
7          NaN  NaN   NaN   4.0   NaN
8          NaN  NaN   NaN   NaN   2.0
9          NaN  NaN   NaN   NaN   1.0
```

---

```
#max of all columns
print (df.where(df1.eq(s, axis=0)).max(axis=1))
0    1.0
1    2.0
2    3.0
3    1.0
4    1.0
5    2.0
6    3.0
7    4.0
8    2.0
9    1.0
dtype: float64
```

---

```
#back fill NaNs
print (df.where(df1.eq(s, axis=0)).bfill(axis=1))
   gene_variant  gene  val1  val2  val3
0           1.0   1.0   1.0   NaN   NaN
1           2.0   2.0   2.0   NaN   NaN
2           3.0   3.0   3.0   NaN   NaN
3           1.0   1.0   1.0   1.0   1.0
4           1.0   1.0   1.0   1.0   NaN
5           2.0   2.0   2.0   2.0   NaN
6           3.0   3.0   3.0   3.0   NaN
7           4.0   4.0   4.0   4.0   NaN
8           2.0   2.0   2.0   2.0   2.0
9           1.0   1.0   1.0   1.0   1.0

#selected first column
print (df.where(df1.eq(s, axis=0)).bfill(axis=1).iloc[:, 0])
0    1.0
1    2.0
2    3.0
3    1.0
4    1.0
5    2.0
6    3.0
7    4.0
8    2.0
9    1.0
Name: gene_variant, dtype: float64
```

Comment: count by order - first val1, then val2 is the solution I was after. Thanks for the great explanation!

Answer (score 1):

You could use `.sort_values()` to get the maximum values. If you pass it multiple columns, it will treat tiebrakers correctly.

```
In [9]: df.sort_values(["val1", "val2", "val3"])
Out[9]: 
  gene_variant gene  val1  val2  val3
0           b1    b     1     1     1
3           c2    c     1     1     1
4           t1    t     1     1     1
9           d4    d     1     1     1
8           d2    d     1     1     2
7           t5    t     1     4     3
1           b2    b     2     1     1
5           t2    t     2     2     2
6           t4    t     2     3     2
2           b3    b     3     1     1
```

Now, in order to do this for each gene you can `groupby('gene')` and apply a custom function.

```
In [11]: df.groupby("gene").apply(
    ...:     lambda _df: _df.sort_values(["val1", "val2", "val3"], ascending=False)
    ...:     .head(1)
    ...:     .squeeze()
    ...: )
Out[11]: 
     gene_variant gene  val1  val2  val3
gene                                    
b              b3    b     3     1     1
c              c2    c     1     1     1
d              d2    d     1     1     2
t              t4    t     2     3     2
```

However, this is not telling you which `val` it was that won the tiebraker.